# 404 Error when reload page in a Tomcat web application

Tags: java, angularjs, tomcat, http-status-code-404, spark-java

I've deployed a Java web application using spark-java and angularJS (ui-router) on a Tomcat9 web server. When I try to reload the page, tomcat will launch an `HTTP Status 404`. This happens with all the views except for the main route '/'.
Tomcat is mapped on port 80, started by root user, and the app has been deployed on webapps/ROOT folder. I don't really know what to do.

I also use html5mode in app.js:

```
app.config(["$locationProvider", function($locationProvider) { 
     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); 
}]);
```

and added `<base href="/">` in `index.html` `<head>`

UPDATE:

In my server.xml I added the following code:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve"/>
</Host>
```

and in /conf/Catalina/localhost/rewrite.config:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) index.html [L]
```

And now i've this console error for all the imported scripts:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

It looks like it replaces all the scripts with `index.html` text.

Comment: Its working at : http://www.click2profit.it/#/login

Comment: I don't know what browser you're using but Chrome removes the # from the URL. I use html5mode in app.js:

`app.config(["$locationProvider", function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);`

Comment: Anyway you have to go to [click2profit.it/login](http://click2profit.it/login) or [click2profit.it/#/login](http://click2profit.it/#/login) and reload the page to get 404 error

Comment: you have to configure server to always point to app entry point for the virtual directories

Comment: @charlietfl would you please be more specific?

Comment: You can't just set html5mode without configuring server. This is explained in the docs

Comment: @charlietfl Ok that's right. Now, how can I do that in tomcat?

Comment: I don't know tomcat at all ... should be easy google search

Comment: Unfortunately it's not

Comment: Add <base href="/app" /> to your index.html in <head> tag
And this to your web.xml
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>StaticServlet</servlet-name>
      <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>StaticServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/app</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

Comment: @Coder002 What sould I write in `index.jsp` file and where should I locate it? i've already added `<base href="/" />` in my index.html `<head> tag

Comment: And did you add this to your web.xml:
<servlet-mapping> <servlet-name>StaticServlet</servlet-name> <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping>

Comment: I did, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Have you properly included the filter in web.XML according to the 'Other Web server' section in [spark java documentation. ?](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html)